# Get the element that changed in Ember `Observes` @each

Tags: ember.js

Is there anyway I can get the element that triggered an observer on `@each`.

```
_propertyChanged: function () {

    //get the object(s) that has triggered this function

}.observes("currentViewProperties.@each.value")
```

Any grown ups around?

Comment: I doubt you can get it.  There are several things that can trigger the observer, including replacing everything in the array with a new array.  It does not make sense to specify "the element" that triggered that change.

Comment: @SteveH. it could be a set of elements too. In my specific case it make sense